# change device names in LVM

Tags: lvm, raid

We have a server crash situation for our Oracle Database Server. The operating system was SLES 10 SP2 and Oracle Release 11.1.0.6.0.
Now the system had this setup before crash.

```
1 boot disk    --- Logical Drive 0---RAID 0---/dev/sda.....which crashed.
2-3 Data disks --- Logical Drive 1---RAID 1 /dev/sdb.....still intact
3-4 Data disks --- Logical Drive 2---RAID 1 /dev/sdc.....still intact
```

When we tried to remove the failed disk , the RAID configuration automatically set the Logical Drive 1 as Logical Drive 0 and Lodical Drive 2 as Logical Drive 1.

So now when we inserted new disk and tried to create Logical Drive ...its giving the option to create Logical Drive 3. :(
But if we go ahead with the SuSE installation, it is detecting the disk as /dev/sdc instead of /dev/sda.
We want to preserve the settings of the previous setup. Because post installation (We also have the system-data backup) I would try to create/restore LVM Setup and that time it will be a problem as the device numbering has changed.

As of now we have removed all the data disks 2-3-4-5 from the system so that we done accidentally install operating system on it.

So how do we go about this now? I really dont wish to mess up with the data disks as otherwise it will be heck of a work.

Or is it so that no matter what the device numbering is there, post installation , if we insert back the data disks, will the system be able to bring back the LVM?

Comment: If you've removed the data disks from the system, wouldn't the new disk show upas logical drive 0? Have you tried that?

Comment: Logical drive sounds like a term of the raid controller. So rather a raid controller problem? Which type/version?

Comment: I don't understand the question. LVM doesn't care about any kind of device numbering, it just assembles the physical volumes that it finds. What's the problem? What errors are you getting?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. The Data disks are out but the RAID Controller console still Holding onto the records for These disks and showing as Failed Disk --> Logical Drive 0 and Failed disk Logical Drive 1. So the newly added disk got the Logical Drive 3 Status.